How to add dev-only dependencies in Deno?
In Node.js, we can use npm install -D foo to add a dependency into package.json > devDependencies. When the package is published and used as a dependency, devDependencies won't be installed.
But in deno.json, there is only imports, no devImports. According to Deno v2 RC announcement, we can use deno add --dev. But this only add contents to deno.lock, not adding anything to deno.json. I tried deno add --dev eslint (not migrating Deno Lint yet), but it complained eslint: command not found.
When package.json exists, it's added to package.json, but I'm trying finding a pure-Deno solution.
I found denoland/deno#26865, but no answers are there.

"…install a dev-only dependency": Can you [edit] the question to clarify what is meant by "install"? Are you referring to the specific scenario of using npm dependencies while using package.json and a local node_modules directory? By default, Deno downloads imported module data into an immutable, global cache. Read more at the docs: Modules and dependencies

@jsejcksn Edited. I'm just finding a thing in Deno like devDependencies in Node.js/npm

Looks like there is no option to add a package as a dev dependency for packages published on JSR. The --dev flag works only for packages published on npm and requires package.json file. Find out more information in the reply of the GitHub issue you have linked: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/26865#issuecomment-2480833535
